# Safety considerations (for parts) for a beginner building with expensive parts

Tags: circuit-design, cmos, circuit-protection, ttl

I'm building for the first time (for me) a circuit with an expensive part (a $80 DEC J11 CPU) and would like to know some "safety" tips so I don't inadvertently destroy the thing while playing with it.

It apparently has both TTL and MOS pins.

I'm looking for guidelines like "don't connect a pin of type A to a pin of type B without a gate of type G in between", or "be sure to add resistors/caps here and here", or "power up this pin/chip before this other pin/chip" or "use a such-and-such circuit to condition the power" ...

(It'll be a breadboard environment if that has additional considerations.)

Comment: Does your CPU come with a data sheet or design guide? It should have recommended layouts, power sequencing, even fan-outs or power/ground plane layouts.

Comment: not really - at the time it was made (in the 70s) I think it was pretty much an internal DEC part - the manual has pinouts and waveforms but I think they were expected to be used by someone who already knew the basics of how to design circuits in that environment.  I'm much more of a beginner ....

Comment: are you looking for stuff like "put a 100 ohm resistor in series with your IO if you want to protect it from shorts hurting the IC"?

Comment: @davidbak then this might simply not yet be the right project for you – start with something simpler. A modern microcontroller comes with good documentation, is cheap and easier to work with. When you know how to design a circuit and layout a board for that, move on towards harder parts. Not the other way around.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - well you could be right I should start simpler - but I've done TTL logic levels, and I've done CMOS logic levels - I just haven't done the combination.  And I'm not looking for _logic_ tips, or even tips on how to debug.  Just tips on how not to fry the thing without learning the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for guidelines like "don't connect a pin of type A to a pin of type B without a gate of type G in between", or "be sure to add resistors/caps here and here", or "power up this pin/chip before this other pin/chip" or "use a such-and-such circuit to condition the power" ...

These "tips" are instructions given in the data sheet and developer's manual.

Engineering (usually) isn't "add a resistor here and there"; it's about reason-based design.

Now, this sounds like something that used to power PDP-11 computers? Don't know whether official documentation is available, but I'm sure there's retrocomputing communities with their own documentation and reference designs.

I'd actually recommend starting with designing a circuit board for a more modern microcontroller. You'll learn a lot of the skills that are useful for doing it right the first time with your expensive one, cheaply, and without being as prone to die due to beginner's mistakes.

Start easy, work towards hard. That also means that starting with modern ICs is the right thing to do, probably, when you want to learn how to build a computer like in the 1970s.

Comment: You're right, it's retro - and I've gone to the retro sites for the thing (it's kind of nice) but again they present circuits they've built without the warnings about "don't do this!".  Maybe what I need is a kind of lab manual, for a course ...

Comment: And I do know that engineering is about reason-based design - I am a software engineer and have been one for 40+ years - but this is a new domain for me and I'm just looking for tips on how not to screw up before I get started.  There were guidelines like that back in my vacuum-tube ham radio days, I thought there might be for TTL/CMOS circuits as well.

Comment: :) I think it's better to think in terms of "you do *this and that* because of XYZ" than to think of "don't do UVW, you'll break abc!". Imagine you'd have to learn C programming by being told not to do a lot of complex ways of shooting yourself in the foot with C, instead of being given a good book on C, or some quality code to work through and understand.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've busted a computer with code.  (Happened in school to a pdp-10.)  Which is why I'm not asking for tips on how to learn this stuff - I am learning it just fine.  And I'm also not worried about frying cheap $2 parts - I've done that too and learned from it already.  But this is an expensive thing.  But if the advice is to try some other kind of mixed TTL/CMOS circuit with inexpensive parts that's good with me - do you have a suggestion?

Comment: then let's do something that interests you application-wise. Are you on the hunt for some specific functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - which by the way should it be a different question I should ask?  But something that interests me application wise would be anything "computery" - e.g., scratch-built 4/8 bit CPU, or scratch-built component of a modern CPU (for demo) e.g., an instruction decoder to microops, ...

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! (I assume here you don't want to play around with programmable logic, where you describe the circuit in a hardware description language and configure it into a programmable array of gates on a chip, but really want discrete gates that you connect via conductors). Let me think about this (nah, as seperate question, that wouldn't be on-topic here, "what project should I do" isn't asking something that is "correctly decidable").

Comment: Problem is that it's kind of a corner use case to have two different logic families in the same CPU component – for external interfaces, sure, if say your graphic card takes CMOS but your keyboard gives you TTL, you need both, but at the core of things, you'd always use CMOS when you have it. So, we're considering something that's *useful* to the CPU, but not necessarily a core component

Comment: I think building a UART would be very cool: The serial port would be TTL, but the shift register, the latching logic, and the parallel interface would be CMOS. It would be something sensible – you can actually interface with that from parallel buses, and it's testable! If it works, it especially works when you connect an arbitrary USB-to-TTL-serial converter cable to your PC and use that to transmit to or receive data  from your UART. It takes a bit of skill to get right: there's timing involved, so you need to have a bit of a usable clock source.

Comment: and, it's a very extensible project. Say, you start with a fixed baudrate, no handshaking. Then you add handshaking. Or more baudrates. Later, clock autodetection, maybe! You use it to have a serially attached memory, by interpreting the first 16 bit you receive as address and read/write flag, and react accordingly with data from a CMOS memory, or by writing to that memory.

Comment: Oh I like that UART suggestion!  OK, I'll go from there thank you very much!  (As I've also wanted to learn about all the different over-the-wire codes too, Manchester, RZ, etc. so I could both encode and decode different protocols ... not just traditional RS-232)

Comment: Nice! Learning about line coding is pretty cool, too. Hint: since, unlike other clocked logic, an UART *needs* to run at a fixed rate, you'll need something to verify partial functionality. There's no stopping during operation! I've been using a software called PulseView, which uses a  library called sigrok to talk to *logic analyzer* devices. In my case, I invested around 10 bucks into a small "Cypress FX2 eval board" (like [this](https://sigrok.org/wiki/Lcsoft_Mini_Board)) that works reasonably well as logic analyzer. Now I can see on my screen how e.g. my clock toggled at 9600 Hz :)